# How are the regression models, confidence intervals and data plotted?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression, emmeans

I have the following model. The data file is in: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_H6YZbdesK7pk5H23mZtp5KhVRKz0Ozl

```
library(nlme)
library(lme4)
library(car)
library(carData)
library(emmeans)
library(ggplot2)
library(Matrix)
library(multcompView)
datos_weight <- read.csv2("D:/investigacion/publicaciones/articulos-escribiendo/pennisetum/pennisetum-agronomicas/data_weight.csv",header=T, sep = ";", dec = ",")

parte_fija_3 <- formula(weight_DM 
                    ~ Genotypes 
                    + Age 
                    + I(Age^2) 
                    + Genotypes*Age 
                    + Genotypes*I(Age^2))
heterocedasticidad_5 <- varComb(varExp(form = ~fitted(.)))
correlacion_4 <- corCompSymm(form = ~ 1|Block/Genotypes)

modelo_43 <- gls(parte_fija_3, 
             weights = heterocedasticidad_5, 
             correlation = correlacion_4, 
             na.action = na.omit, 
             data = datos_weight)
anova(modelo_43)

#response
Denom. DF: 48 
                   numDF  F-value p-value
(Intercept)            1 597.3828  <.0001
Genotypes              3   2.9416  0.0424
Age                    1 471.6933  <.0001
I(Age^2)               1  22.7748  <.0001
Genotypes:Age          3   5.9425  0.0016
Genotypes:I(Age^2)     3   0.7544  0.5253
```

Now I want to graph the regression models with confidence intervals and data, separated for each genotype. I have used `ggplot2` and I have plot the data, I have not been able to add the regression models with confidence intervals.

```
library(ggplot2)
rango_X <- c(30,90) #x axis
rango_Y <- c(0,175) #y axis
ggplot(datos_weight, aes(x = Age, y = weight_DM)) +
  geom_point() + 
  xlab("Age") + 
  ylab("Dry matter") +
  xlim(rango_X) +
  ylim(rango_Y) +
  facet_wrap(~ Genotypes, ncol = 2)
```

The graph is as follows:

[image]

For the next analysis of the same data, where there is no interaction with the quadratic age: `Genotypes*I(Age^2)`, how would you add the regression models with confidence intervals to the graph?

```
parte_fija_3 <- formula(weight_DM 
                        ~ Genotypes 
                        + Age
                        + I(Age^2)
                        + Genotypes*Age) 
                        #+ Genotypes*I(Age^2))
> anova(modelo_44)
Denom. DF: 51 
              numDF  F-value p-value
(Intercept)       1 609.3684  <.0001
Genotypes         3   3.7264  0.0169
Age               1 479.0973  <.0001
I(Age^2)          1  21.9232  <.0001
Genotypes:Age     3   6.4184  0.0009
```

The linear slopes from `modelo_44` are:

```
(tendencias_em_lin <- emtrends(modelo_44,
                                "Genotypes",
                                var = "Age"))
Genotypes Age.trend        SE df lower.CL upper.CL
C          1.613619 0.1723451 51 1.267622 1.959616
E          1.665132 0.2024104 51 1.258776 2.071488
K          1.888587 0.2001627 51 1.486744 2.290430
M          1.059897 0.1205392 51 0.817905 1.301890
```

The quadratic slopes are?

```
(tendencias_em_quad <- emtrends(modelo_44,
                                "Genotypes",
                                var = "I(Age^2)"))
 Genotypes I(Age^2).trend           SE df    lower.CL   upper.CL
 C            0.013379926 0.0014290639 51 0.010510961 0.01624889
 E            0.013807066 0.0016783618 51 0.010437614 0.01717652
 K            0.015659927 0.0016597235 51 0.012327893 0.01899196
 M            0.008788536 0.0009994958 51 0.006781965 0.01079511

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Or the stimate from summary: `I(Age^2) = -0.01511`? I believe that the slope is constant for all genotypes because the `Genotypes*I(Age^2)` interaction has not been tested in `modelo_44`:

```
summary(modelo_44)
Generalized least squares fit by REML
Model: parte_fija_3 
....
Coefficients:
                   Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
(Intercept)    -73.32555 11.236777 -6.525496  0.0000
GenotypesE       7.22267  9.581979  0.753776  0.4544
GenotypesK      -9.83285  9.165962 -1.072757  0.2884
GenotypesM      17.87000  8.085229  2.210203  0.0316
Age              3.43593  0.450041  7.634687  0.0000
I(Age^2)        -0.01511  0.004065 -3.717475  0.0005
GenotypesE:Age   0.05151  0.246724  0.208788  0.8354
GenotypesK:Age   0.27497  0.241923  1.136595  0.2610
GenotypesM:Age  -0.55372  0.195398 -2.833808  0.0066
...
```

**Questions**

1. How do I add the regression models with confidence intervals and data for each genotype in separate graphs such as those presented, with `ggplot2` or another option, if I had to plot for the models: `modelo_43` and `modelo_44`?
2. Did I correctly calculate the estimate of the quadratic slope with `emtrends` for `modelo_44`, how is it correct?

**Thank you very much for the reply**

Comment: Check out `?geom_smooth`.

Answer (score 1):

This question looks vaguely familiar -- have you posted it before? Maybe I'm thinking of some similar question from somebody else.

It seems that you are trying to plot apples, oranges, and bananas all on the same scale. I'm not sure what units the response variable (dry matter is in); let's say its in kg. Then the results in `tendencies_em_lin` are in kg per year, and those in `tendencies_em_quad` are in kg per year^2. These are three different scales, and it makes no sense to "show the data" on plots of those.

What I think it does make sense to do is something like this:

```
emm <- emmeans(modelo_44, ~ Genotype*Age,
    at = list(Age = seq(from = 40, to = 80, by = 5)))
```

This will obtain predictions for the given ages with each genotype. Now you can plot them as follows:

```
plotobj <- emmip(emm, Genotype ~ Age, CIs = TRUE)
plotobj
```

The returned `plotobj` is a ggplot object that you can add the data to, using techniques as shown in an example at the end of the graphics section in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/basics.html#plots.

Or, you can use `dat = as.data.frame(emm)` as a data frame containing the results you need, and plot them however you like. Again, you may use **ggplot2** techniques to add the observed data to these plots.

Either way, the linear trends will be visible as increases or decreases in the plotted EMMs, and the quadratic trends will be visible as curvature in these paths.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I asked about the intercepts last time at [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52866203/hypothesis-test-for-intercepts-in-general-mixed-linear-models-with-r) with the same data, now the the main question is to graph the information of the models of each genotype. The genotypes are names of grasses. C = Cameroon, K = King Grass, M = Maralfalfa, E = Elephant.

Comment: The units of measure are Age = days, weight_DM = kg/cut. The weight is dry matter of pastures. The model I want to obtain for each genotype is like this: `y = a + bX + cX^2`, where y = weight_DM and X = days, a = intercept, b = linear slope, c = quadratic slope; and graph those models with the confidence interval. Thank you.